# export task - "StatusMessage": "Task expired and automatically canceled"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-backup

I used the ec2 create-instance-export-task command to export one instance with a single 8GB volume, and waited for over 100 hours. And today, I checked the progress with the describe-export-task command and found the following results.
No results were detected in any search engine for the error message.

Is there any way to check why it's not progressing?
I'm using a cli for Windows on Windows 11.
Among the contents below, I arbitrarily deleted the Task ID.

```
{
"ExportTasks": [
{
"ExportTaskId": "export-i-0000000000000",
"ExportToS3Task": {
"ContainerFormat": "ova",
"DiskImageFormat": "vmdk",
"S3Bucket": "backup-00000",
"S3Key": "vms/export-i-0000000000000.ova"
},
"InstanceExportDetails": {},
"State": "cancelled",
"StatusMessage": "Task expired and automatically canceled"
}
]
}
```

wait 100hrs, create new instance with volume